# Use default value if user skips input

Tags: java

I want to ask the size of the array from the user. If the user does not enter the size and press the enter button, I want to use array size as 10 (default value). I am not able to do it.
Here is my simple java code.

> ```
>     System.out.print("Enter the size of Stack: ");
>     int size = sc.nextInt();
> ```

Check out the image for reference.

[image]

I am a beginner in java.

Comment: `nextInt` is very literal: it expects the user to enter an `int` and not return until the users does. Use something like `nextLine` to get input from the user and then check if it's empty and parse it to an int only if it isn't. Also: I'd avoid `Scanner`: it's not actually well-suited for user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that the `sc.nextInt();` is waiting as long as it can find an `int` input.

A workaround for your problem could be to read the whole line and then try to parse this line to an `int`.

If the user-input is not an int (e.g. `abcdefg` or an empty String (only enter-button)), then the parsing will fail. Therefore in the `catch` block the default value is set.

E.g. it could look like this:

```java
String sizeString = sc.nextLine();

int size;

try {
  size = Integer.parseInt(sizeString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  size = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` you can check if the enter key was pressed by comparing the `input` against an empty string.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the size of Stack: ");
        // The replaceAll cleans the input by removing all non numeric characters
        String input = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");;
        int size;
        
        // If the input is empty set size to 10 otherwise parse the string input as an integer
        if(input.equals("")){
            size = 10;
        }else{
            size = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        
        System.out.println(size);
```

Output:

```
Enter the size of Stack: 
10
```